# I want time syncronization in asp.net webforms project

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a project in asp.net which take time duration.
Now I want if another member login to that project so he will have the same time as of another login user remaining time duration.
not start from the beginning.
please help me about it....?

Comment: What did you try so far? You need to explain better what's the issue that you have, so someone can help you. What do you use to track time?

Comment: I want a synchronized countdown timer that shows the same remaining time to all members of  that project.

Comment: e-g if I (jkl) am login to project xyz and its time duration is 10 minutes and another member abc also login to xyz project after 5 minutes so we both (jkl and abc) have remaining time in that project will be 5 minutes.His(abc) time will not start from 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to persist the initial time somehow, probably in a database. 
Once a project is created, it'll have a variable of some sort (say, "timeToCountdown").
When the time-cap has been decided (say, 90 minutes) you'd do something like:

```
timeToCountdown = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(90);
```

Now, whenever a user is logged in, you'd simply start and show the user a timer that counts until "timeToCountdown".

Comment: But if one member spend 5 minutes on that project.And at same time another member will loge in so he will have  85 minutes remaining not 90 minutes.i want something like that

Comment: @AbidAkhtar decrease that counter in the database every minute. Every minute, with an Ajax call, call a function which decreases 'timeToCountdown' by -1 minutes. This way, every user which is viewing this project will decrease the countdown every minute. Before decreasing you should obviously check if the time didn't already pass (`timeToCountdown == DateTime.Now`).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here see below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV8tl.jpg)